# Before pass a pointer to a function I have to initialize it always?

Tags: c, function, null, initialization, malloc

Before pass a pointer defined in `main()` to a function I have to initialize it or can I initialize it into the function? Or is it the same? And can I initialize it with `NULL`?

I have write some codes for example. It's all right?

**[1]** The initialization of `int *example` is in a function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define DIM (10)

void function (int *);

int main ()
{
    int *example;

    function (example);

    /* other code */

    free(example);

    return 0;
}

void function (int *example)
{
    /* INITIALIZATION */
    example = malloc (DIM * sizeof(int));

    /* other code */

    return;
}
```

**[2]** The initialization of `int *example` is in the main.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define DIM (10)

void function (int *);

int main ()
{
    int *example;

    /* INITIALIZATION */    
    example = malloc (DIM * sizeof(int));

    function (example);

    /* other code */

    free(example);

    return 0;
}

void function (int *example)
{
    /* other code */

    return;
}
```

**[3]** The initialization is in the `main()` with `NULL`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function (int *);

int main ()
{
    /* INITIALIZATION */
    int *example = NULL;

    function (example);

    /* other code */

    free(example);

    return 0;
}

void function (int *example)
{
    /* other code */

    return;
}
```

**[4]** The initialization is in the function with `NULL`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function (int *);

int main ()
{
    int *example;

    function (example);

    /* other code */

    free(example);

    return 0;
}

void function (int *example)
{
    example = NULL;

    /* other code */

    return;
}
```

**[5]** The same as [1] but with `example = realloc (example, DIM * sizeof(int));`

**[6]** The same as [2] but with `example = realloc (example, DIM * sizeof(int));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should learn more about how function arguments work. Generally in C arguments are passed by value (arrays and functions are treated differently, but first things first). So in [1] you try to free not initialised pointer, since the assignment in the function does not do anything with the variable example in main. [2] is good. In [3] you do not allocate memory at all, so any access to what example points to will be invalid. [5] and [6] are not good since you pass not initialised value to realloc.

Comment: If in [1] I change `int *example;` into `int *example = NULL;` then it's right? (with _"[3]"_ do you mean [3] or [4]? I ask you this because for error I wrote [3] and [3], now I have correct)

Comment: [1] - it is better than before, since will not crash, but still not good, because the memory allocated in function is never freed. The example variable in main is NULL, and free(example) does nothing

Comment: Both [3] and [4] are problematic in the sense that no memory is allocated, so any access to what example points to will be invalid.

Comment: If I change the [1] into [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b3f9b68e4deeeb7aaddf/9c5be807c31485fa0e100db0937ce2ae00468d4d#file-before-pass-a-pointer-to-a-function-i-have-to-initialize-it-always) it's correct?

Comment: No, the memory is not freed - "example" in main is NULL, so the call free(example) does nothing.

Comment: In the last link I'd posted I'd made some errors (I had passed to the function `example`, and not `*example`, and in `function()` I had wrote `example` in place of `*example`). Now I have correct them: is [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8471731) correct?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45470/discussion-between-wojtek-surowka-and-user)